# How to Use Multiple Columns As XAxis in Excel with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, charts, epplus

I have 2-3 datasets. i want use first elements as a single X-Axis and plot my data.  I cannot manage it. Excel always ignores second X-axis.Here is c# code  that i used which is taken from [EPPlus site](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ).

```
    var chart = Worksheet.Drawings.AddChart(name, eChartType.Line);
    chart.Title.Text = name;
    var serie1 = chart.Series.Add(Worksheet.Cells["B2:B50"], Worksheet.Cells["A2:A50"]);

    var chartType2 = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.Line);
    var serie2 = chartType2.Series.Add(Worksheet.Cells["D2:D60"], Worksheet.Cells["C2:C60"]);
    chartType2.UseSecondaryAxis = true;
    chartType2.XAxis.Deleted = false;
    chartType2.XAxis.TickLabelPosition = eTickLabelPosition.High;
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb0iJ.jpg) is 2 result of same dataset. First one is the one i need which is generated by plot.ly. Second generated by excel.

X-axes is completely random, not equally spaced and different size.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i finally made it work.
There are 3 things. 
Firstly chart type was wrong. Use one of XYScatter types. i used XYScatterLinesNoMarkers.

Secondly X-Axis was datetime. Pass datetime object to cell value as itself and use cell formatting.

Thirdly set

```
    chartType2.UseSecondaryAxis = false;
    chartType2.XAxis.Deleted = true;
```

it worked for me.